# Error in sticking actions to component react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component which binds actions with it's props like this

I am not including the complete api call code in the handleButtonclick function here to avoid unnecessary code.

```
class LogInComponent extends Component {
static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
handleLoginButtonClick() {
    let token;

    $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {
        token = JSON.stringify(response.auth_token)  
        this.props.setAuthToken(token);
        this.context.router.push('/app')
    });

}

render(){
    return (
        <div className="LoginPage">
                    <button onClick={this.handleLoginButtonClick.bind(this)}>login</button>
        </div>
    );
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state)=> ({
    auth_token: state.Data.auth_token
})
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({setAuthToken: actions.setAuthToken}, dispatch);
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(LogInComponent);
```

This is where my action and reducer are there:

```
   import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    list: [],
    selectedRows: [],
    currentItem: {},
    auth_token:null
}

const FETCH_LIST = 'FETCH_LIST'
const fetchList = ()=> (dispatch)=> {
    dispatch({type: FETCH_LIST});
    fetch('/api/items?n=50')
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => dispatch(fetchListSuccess(data)))
        .catch(err => dispatch(fetchListError(err)))
}


const FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS'
const fetchListSuccess = (list)=> {
    console.log('Received List: ', list)
    return {
        type: FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS,
        list
    }
}

const FETCH_LIST_ERROR = 'FETCH_LIST_ERROR'
const fetchListError = (error)=> {
    console.error(error)
    return {
        type: FETCH_LIST_ERROR,
        error: error.message
    }
}


const SELECT_ROWS = 'SELECT_ROWS'
const selectRows = (ids)=> {
    return {
        type: SELECT_ROWS,
        ids
    }
}

const SET_AUTH_TOKEN = 'SELECT_ROWS'
const setAuthToken = (token)=> {
    return {
        type: SET_AUTH_TOKEN,
        payload: token
    }
}

const SET_CURRENT_ITEM = 'SET_CURRENT_ITEM'
const setCurrentItem = (item)=> {
    return {
        type: SET_CURRENT_ITEM,
        item
    }
}


export const actions = {
    fetchList,
    selectRows,
    setCurrentItem,
    setAuthToken
}


export default function DataReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_LIST:
            return {...state, isLoading: true }
        case FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, isLoading: false, list: [...action.list] }
        case FETCH_LIST_ERROR:
            return {...state, isLoading: false, hasError: action.error }
        case SELECT_ROWS:
            return {...state, selectedRows: [...action.ids]}
        case SET_CURRENT_ITEM:
            return {...state, currentItem: {...action.item}}
        case SET_AUTH_TOKEN:
            return {...state, auth_token:action.payload}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I am getting an error like this 
[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In which line is error thrown?

Comment: Where is your fetchListSuccess function that youre calling after fetch is successful?

Comment: wait I will add all the actions which I have. Please check the updated ques

Comment: What is line 18 of data.js? That seems like where the error is from the call stack

Comment: .catch(err => dispatch(fetchListError(err))) This one? What does this has to do with the setAuthToken action?